# Access MailItem properties of Outlook msg attachment

Tags: vbscript, outlook

I'm trying to use vbscript to extract mail item details from hundreds of old Exchange Journal Outlook PST files.  All the items in the PST archives are made up of an "envelope" mail item with an .msg attachment that's the actual e-mail whose properties I want to capture.

I can access the attachment object, but cannot extract the MailItem properties and collections listed below, presumably because the attachment isn't opening as a Mail Item.  I've tried to use the PropertyAccessor object, but I can't get any results from it.

The only workaround I've come up with is to use the SaveAsFile method to save each attachment to file, then CreateItemFromTemplate to open the saved file, which then provides full access to the Mail Item properties of the object.  However, the delay caused by the disk operations is excessive.  My basic "workaround" code for returning a "objMsg" MailItem object is:

```
    Set objOL=WScript.CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    set objNS=objOL.GetNameSpace("MAPI")
    Set objPST = objNS.Folders(strPSTname).Folders("Inbox").Items
    Set objItem = objPST.Items(1)
    objItem.Attachments(1).SaveAsFile(conTempPath)
    Set objMsg = objOL.CreateItemFromTemplate(conTempPath)
```

Is anyone aware of a better method for accessing the Mail Item properties of a .msg attachment?

```
    objItem.Class
    objItem.ReceivedTime
    objItem.SenderEmailAddress
    objItem.SenderName
    objItem.SentOnBehalfOfName
    objItem.Subject
    objItem.Attachments
    objItem.Recipients
    objItem.To
    objItem.Cc
    objItem.Bcc
```

Comment: Thanks Dmitry.  It appears SaveAsFile/CreateItemFromTemplate or Redemption are the only options.  If I can get Redemption working with vbscript it'll post the code here (unless someone else does it first).  Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the best you can do in the Outlook Object Model. Your options are:

1. Extended MAPI (usable from either C++ or Delphi) - call `IAttach::OpenProperty(PR_ATTACH_DATA_OBJ, IID_IMessage, ...)`
2. [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (I am its author), which is usable from any language - its [RDOAttachment](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOAttachment.htm) object exposes the `EmbeddedMsg` property.